# Add dynamically generated input fields into a JSON object with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Users can create any number of input fields and on save the values are saved as a JSON and sent to the server.

I can't add these user generated input field values into the JSON format and I get no output result of the JSON.

I'm doing it as below:

```
$(function () { 
$(document).on('click', '.send', function (e) {
    var dataGroup = [];
    $('.form-group').each(function () {
        var emailData = {};
        $(this).find(':input[data-name]').each(function () {
            emailData[$(this).emailData('name')] = this.value
        });
        dataGroup.push(emailData);
    });      

           $('#result').val(JSON.stringify(dataGroup))
 });
});
```

This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lhpo8pL/19/). How can you add each input field into the JSON?

Comment: Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/9Lhpo8pL/19/ ?

Comment: @Rahil yes thats the jsfiddle I put up

Comment: No I mean I provided you the solution in that fiddle. Its not perfect but you'll get a idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Lhpo8pL/21/
There was a couple of things:

1. The `data` attribute should be addressed like this
   `$(this).data('name')` instead of `$(this).emailData('name')`
2. 'send' is an ID, not a class
3. The text area has `#output` id, not `#result`